# nginx - serve single file on a location block without changing the path

Tags: nginx

I have a single page web application. I want to set up nginx to serve files under a folder directly, and for all other requests, I want it to serve a single html file. The setup I wanna achieve is as follows:

```
.
.
.
location /static/ {
    # Serve directly here
}

location / {
    # Serve single file here (index.html), without changing the path
}
.
.
.
```

Answers to similar questions I found suggested using a url rewrite, but as far as I know, that would redirect the user to a new url, hence changing the path.

What I want is, whatever the user types except something beginning with static, nginx serves the index.html file without changing the path, because I will be loading dynamic content to the webpage using the path variable.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simplest way would be

```
location / {
    try_files /index.html /index.html;
}
```